# Build Android Module ERROR: Command Line Tools

Tags: android, xcode, macos, titanium

I try to build an Android Module with Titanium, but I always get this error message:

> .../osx/3.2.0.GA/module/android/build.xml:326: The following error
>       occurred while executing this line:
>       .../osx/3.2.0.GA/module/android/build.xml:281: exec returned: 2 You
>       may need to install the Command Line Tools package through XCode, in
>       case you haven't done so yet.

I have installed the CLT three times but I alway get this message.

Here my build.properties:

```
titanium.platform=/Users/me/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.2.0.GA/android
android.platform=/Users/me/Documents/android-sdk/platforms/android-10
google.apis=/Users/me/Documents/android-sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-10
android.ndk=/Users/me/Documents/android-ndk-r9d
```

I am working on OSX 10.9.3 with the newest Titanium Version and Xcode 5.1.1.

Does anyone have a solution for my problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that an error in the Module was the Problem. Now its working